# Swiftui with delegate functions for mkmapview and uitextfield

Tags: swift, delegates, mkmapview, textfield, swiftui

I'm practicing and reading up on `SwiftUI` and I am starting off by making a simple app where you can type a location into a `TextField` View from `swiftUI` and then on enter the `mkmapview` within `SwiftUI` again will go to that location that I searched for. I can't for the life of me seem to grasp how to get this functionality setup with my `mkmapview`.

Additionally I can't even find a way to dismiss the keyboard from `Textfield` without doing a navigation or rendering a new view or removing a view.

Can anyone point to me how I can dismiss my keyboard? I'm used to `resignFirstResponder()` or `didFinishEditing()`.
Also, does anyone have any suggestions on how to assign functionality to the `MKMapView` from `swiftUI` or am I looking at this all wrong?

I figured in my Textfield's onCommit handler I would call a function that could pass necessary data to `MapView` and handle that but I haven't been able to find a good way to do it.

```swift
struct MainView : View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .offset(y: 50)
                //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            SearchField(text: "")
                .offset(y: -(UIScreen.main.bounds.height) + 60)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MapView : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 34.011286, longitude: -116.166868)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct SearchField : View {
    @State var text: String
    @State var showDetails: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .offset(y: 55)
            TextField($text, placeholder: Text("City, State, or Address"), onEditingChanged: { body in
                print(body)

            }, onCommit: {
                print(self.text)
            })
                .padding()
                .offset(x: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit Note: my code above works, it will build a full screen map view with a text field on it and the text field takes text and will update it's state. My question is about moving forward from this with getting functionality to mapview and hiding my damn keyboard on return

Comment: I think you need to get `SearchField` to bind to the text property in `MainView`, but I've not managed to get that working yet.

EDIT: posted proposed approach below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys,

So from what I have seen so far keyboards will only dismiss on some ui change but I found a pretty elegant solution!

By using a Binding declaration for a boolean "didEnter" which I can pass between views, when the user hit's return on the keyboard the onCommit() function is called within the TextField view. So I added a toggle for onCommit that actually switches my TextField view to a Text view that displays the text simulating the same look, then after some task is completed I toggle didEnter again which switches back to the TextField.

Still feels like a workaround but works for now.

```
struct InputView : View {
    @Binding var text:          String
    @Binding var didEnter:      Bool
    @State   var searchType:    SearchType

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).frame(width: 310, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .offset(y: -20)
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 290, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                if(!didEnter){
                    TextField($text, placeholder: Text("City, State, Address")) {
                        print(self.text)
                        self.didEnter.toggle()
                    }
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 40, alignment: .leading)
                        .offset(x: -20)
                }
                else{
                    Text(self.text).frame(width: 220, height: 40, alignment: .leading)
                        .offset(x: -20)
                }
                Text("Select Location:").bold().fontWeight(.medium)
                    .offset(y: -40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To dismiss the keyboard when pressing return button in TextField, you can use:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
```

Calling it on TextField's onCommit method:

```
TextField($searchString, placeholder: Text("Search...")) {
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
   }
   .font(.system(size: 23))
   .padding()
```

Answer (score 0):

My gut feel is you need to pass the binding into the `SearchField` like this:

```
struct MainView : View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .offset(y: 50)
            //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            SearchField(text: $text)
                .offset(y: -(UIScreen.main.bounds.height) + 60)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct MapView : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 34.011286, longitude: -116.166868)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}

struct SearchField : View {
    @State var text: Binding<String>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .offset(y: 55)
            TextField(text, placeholder: Text("City, State, or Address"), onEditingChanged: { body in
                print(self.text)

            }, onCommit: {
                print(self.text)
            })
                .padding()
                .offset(x: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So both ways work, as a binding or the way I implemented

Comment: but this isn't addressing my main issue of not being able to add functionality to mkmapview within swiftui or handling my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Use a coordinator. Check out their Landmarks example. Search for delegate in the tutorial. I’m writing on the go so can’t post the link.

I did this for UIImagePickerController

Comment: This? https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: You're right, I ended up using a coordinator to get the behavior I wanted with mapkit, makes a lot more sense.

Also, I'm convinced we are just at a point where we can't expect SwiftUI to do everything it's advertised to do so simply, still very early.

Comment: @alexbuga, is your code for `UIImagePickerController` someplace? I can get everything working *except* it won't present a *second* time after the first time is dismissed. Any chance you have something that works? (I'm still not convinced it's simply a beta 1 bug.